# Binomial distribution buy candies randomly

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem

A candy shop makes 5000 candies per day, of which 30% have strawberry flavour. 
Every Sunday, Jack buys 15 candies randomly. On average, how many of these candies will have strawberry flavour?

Is it just $15*0.3=4.5$? but $4.5$ is not a whole number...so what is the right way?*`*

Determine the probability that on a given Sunday, there
will be at least 6 candies with strawberry flavour that Jack has bought.

$ 1-\mathop{\rm Binomcdf}(15, 0.3 ,5)$ ? Am I right?

In a month of 4 Sundays, what is the probability that Jack will not
bring home at least 6 candies with strawberry flavour on any of the Sundays.

$1-\mathop{\rm Binomcdf}(15,0.7,5)$ and multiply 4 times???

Answer (score 0):

Since the sample size of candies is 5,000, I think you are justified in using the binomial and everything that you said looks about right! (If you had a super computer, I think you'd use the hypergeometric) For your third question I'd calculate it as $Binomcdf(15,0.3,5)$ which I am pretty sure is exactly what you wrote, but I am too lazy to double check it.

Comment: for que 1, asking the average number, I get 4.5 which is not a whole number/ integer...i think i did something wrong but i dont know where went wrong.
for que 3, why B(15,0.3,5)? The question is asking the prob that will not bring at least 6 candies. so p(not strawberry)=0.7,hence,1-B(15,0.7,5), am i right? in any 4 sundays, multiply 4 times the answer?